# Triominos Bridge Rules

Tags: triominos

I recently had an argument with my wife about a "correct" bridge in triominos.

I got a "bridge" figure, but with a flaw: the numbers at the tops of the two tiles didn't match. (see image).

So my questions:
1. is this allowed? 
2. does this qualify for "bridge" extra points?

My suggestions:
1. Yes, it's allowed, since my printed rules do not forbid it.
2. No, allowed but no extra points, since it's not a "real" bridge.

[image: Triominos mismatching tile tops]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must match all three numbers so this is not allowed. So you can not place the tile there.

In [this version of the rules:](http://gambiter.com/domino/Triominoes.html)

> Bridges are made by matching one side of the tile and the point opposite. Score the tile's points plus a 40 point bonus

Comment: That answers question 2 ("does this qualify for bridge extra points"), whereas the answer will be "no extra points, if top points don't match".
Question 1 ("is this allowed") is still open or undefined, even in the rules you mentioned it's not explicitly prohibited to lay down a tile like mentioned.
I also contacted GoliathToys, but I don't think they gonna answer...

Comment: It is not allowed. I have an older version of the game in which the rules where clearer but I can not scan them now.

Answer (score 0):

Bridges are made by matching one side of the tile **and the point opposite**. The point opposite has to match, no other tiles accepted. The rules are clear.

Comment: Welcome to Board & Card games. Please expand your answer, and preferably add a link to rules. Because as it is now, this answer does not add anything new.